# OneDrive API help in getting download link of file

Tags: onedrive

I need to get download URL of the file using OneDrive API.

This works
 string url = "https://apis.live.net/v5.0/" + FILE_ID + "/shared_read_link?access_token=" + AUTH_TOKEN

but this doesn't
 string url = "https://apis.live.net/v5.0/" + FILE_ID + "/content?suppress_redirects=true?access_token=" + AUTH_TOKEN;

Its throwing error, unauthorized.. can someone tell why?

Thanks
Sujit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

& should have been used in place of ?. So correct answer is

string url = "https://apis.live.net/v5.0/" + FILE_ID + "/content?suppress_redirects=true&access_token=" + AUTH_TOKEN;